# Setting a dropdown selected value when generating a html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a html table with a dropdown and a textbox from an array. I am storing array value property value in textbox and based on the value comin in the key property I want to to set the selected value of the dropdown in each row.
 How can I set the dropdown value.
My code is like this. Everything is done I want only to set dropdown selected value.

```
var filtrnode=[arrayvalue];

$.each(filterNodeData.FilterData, function (i, item) {
     debugger;
     var newData = filterNodeData.FilterData[i];
     trHTML += '<tr><td>' + '<select class="form-control"><option value="and">And</option><option value="or">Or</option></select>' + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + '<input class="form-control" size=35 type="text" id="filterValue" value= ' + filterNodeData.FilterData[i].value + '>' + '</td>' +
          '<td><input type="button" id="delFilter" class="delHeader btn btn-md red" value="Delete" onclick="deleteFilter(this)" ></td>' +
          '<td><input type="button" id="AddFilter" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" value="Add" onclick="insertFilter()" ></td>' + '</tr>';
});
$('#filterTable').append(trHTML);
```

Thanks

Comment: On which key or value you want to set dropdown value? Show us your `FilterData` and key to be set in dropdown option.

Comment: It will be dynamic based on the value stored in the key in each element dropdown will be selected

Comment: As you are setting `.value` for textbox, similarily what is the key for `dropdown` on the basis of you wants to set selected.

Comment: filterdata is contain data like this  [{"key":"and","value":"zzzxxz"},{"key":"and","value":"sdddsds"},{"key":"and","value":"ewewewew"},{"key":"and","value":"wewrerrer"}]

Comment: based on the key I want to select dropdown

Comment: try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it by getting the option selected for that index like,

```
$.each(filterNodeData.FilterData, function (i, item) {
     var newData = filterNodeData.FilterData[i],
         value=newData.value,
         key = newData.key;
     trHTML += '<tr><td>' + '<select class="form-control">'+
             '<option value="and" '+(key=='and'?'selected':'')+'>And</option>'+
             '<option value="or" '+(key=='or'?'selected':'')+'>Or</option>'+
         '</select></td>' +
          '<td>' + '<input class="form-control" size=35 type="text" id="filterValue" value= ' + value + '>' + '</td>' +
          '<td><input type="button" id="delFilter" class="delHeader btn btn-md red" value="Delete" onclick="deleteFilter(this)" ></td>' +
          '<td><input type="button" id="AddFilter" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" value="Add" onclick="insertFilter()" ></td>' + '</tr>';
});
$('#filterTable').append(trHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // store your html as a variable, `` alows you to use lines in string
    var row = `
  <tr>
  <td><select class="form-control"><option value="and">And</option><option value="or">Or</option></select></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" size=35 type="text" id="filterValue"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="delFilter" class="delHeader btn btn-md red" value="Delete" onclick="deleteFilter(this)" ></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="AddFilter" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" value="Add" onclick="insertFilter()" ></td>
  </tr>
  `
  var filtrnode = [{arrayvalue}];

  $.each(filtrnode, function(i, item) {
    // make a jQuery object from your html variable
    var newRow = $(row);
    // and now you are free to use jQuery selectors and functions on it
    newRow.find("select option[value="+ item.key +"]").prop("selected", true);
    newRow.find("input[type='text']").val(item.value);
    $('#filterTable').append(newRow);
  });  
});
```

Storing your HTML code as a variable using `` allows you tu use line breaks and create a code which is easier to read. After you create a jQuery object from your stored HTML you can access all of jQuery functions which is cool. This makes your code less prone to mistakes and typos. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dallows/8oeeu1j9/).